# Where is my calculation wrong?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

For the following quadratic form $$f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x^TA^TWAx}-2\mathbf{b^TWAx}+\mathbf{b^TWb}$$ where $\mathbf{x}\in R^m$ $\mathbf{A}\in R^{n\times m}$ $\mathbf{b}\in R^n$ and $\mathbf{W}\in R^{n\times n}$ ($\mathbf{W}$ is a diagonal matrix) the value of $\mathbf{x}$ that minimizes $f(\mathbf{x})$ is $\mathbf{x}^*=\left(\mathbf{A^TWA}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{b^TWA}$. When I put this value I get $$f(\mathbf{x^*})=\left[\left(\mathbf{A^TWA}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{b^TWA}\right]^T\mathbf{b^TWA}-2\mathbf{b^TWA\left(A^TWA\right)^{-1}b^TWA+b^TWb}.$$ But this is not what is written in Convex optimization book by Stephen Boyd on page 82. The expression provided by the book is as follows $$f(\mathbf{x^*})=\mathbf{b^TWb-b^TWA\left(A^TWA\right)^{-1}A^TWb}$$ where is the mistake in my answer?

Comment: If $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ then you cannot do $x^{T}A^{T}$ and obtain an element of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to multiply it with $W$.

Is $x\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$, by any chance?

Comment: sorry I should have written $x\in R^m$. Thank you for correction. But if with this correction I do not know how to get the second expression for $f(\mathbf{x^*})$.

Comment: Are you sure the minimizing value for $x$ is $(A^{T}WA)^{-1}b^{T}WA$?
I get $(A^{T}WA)^{-1}A^{T}Wb$. Can you check?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I use $f'(\mathbf{x})=2\mathbf{A^TWAx}-2\mathbf{b^TWA}=0$. From this expression I got. How you calculated $f'(\mathbf{x})$?

Comment: I think your value is correct. I should have taken the trannspose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is that the minimizing value for $x$ is
$$x=(A^{T}WA)^{-1}A^{T}Wb$$
not $x=(A^{T}WA)^{-1}b^{T}WA$.

You can see this easily if you differentiate $f(x)$ with respect to $x^{T}$

$$f(x) = x^{T}A^{T}WAx - 2b^{T}WAx + b^{T}Wb$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{T}}(x) = \frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x^{T}}A^{T}WAx + x^{T}A^{T}WA\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^{T}}- 2b^{T}WA\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^{T}}\\
= A^{T}WAx + (x^{T}A^{T}WA)^{T} - (2b^{T}WA)^{T}\\
= A^{T}WAx + A^{T}WAx - 2A^{T}Wb\\
= 2A^{T}WAx - 2A^{T}Wb
\overset{!}{=}0$$
$$\implies A^{T}WAx = A^{T}Wb$$
$$\implies x = (A^{T}WA)^{-1}A^{T}Wb$$

Now if you substitute that in $f$ you get the desired result.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer :).

Comment: Of course. My pleasure. cx

Answer (score 0):

The first two terms in
$f(\mathbf{x^*})
=\left[\left(\mathbf{A^TWA}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{b^TWA}\right]^T\mathbf{b^TWA}
-2\mathbf{b^TWA\left(A^TWA\right)^{-1}b^TWA
+b^TWb}$
are substantially the same
once the transpose and inverse
are done.

For example,

$\mathbf{b^TWA\left(A^TWA\right)^{-1}b^TWA}\\
=\mathbf{b^TWA\left(A^{-1}W^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}\right)b^TWA}\\
=\mathbf{b^T(A^T)^{-1}b^TWA}
$

Comment: No I do not get $\mathbf{b^T(A^T)^{-1}b^TWA}$ after solving $\mathbf{\left[(A^TWA)^{-1}b^TWA\right]^T\mathbf{b^TWA}}$

Comment: instead I get $$\mathbf{A^TWbA^{-1}W^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}b^TWA}$$. I used the fact that for a positive semidefinite matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ we have $(\mathbf{Q^{-1}})^T=(\mathbf{Q^T})^{-1}$

Comment: Further, I think the inverse property that you used in your answer relies on the assumption that $\mathbf{A}$ is invertable however it may not be the case.

Comment: what your take on this?